# How to start the tutorials-IoT.Sensors services to start in linux instance in FIWARE Lab

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, filab

I recently deployed an instance of Ubuntu 16.04 on FIWARE Lab and accessed it using putty, I downloaded docker & docker-compose, I successfully installed fiware-orion & mongo-db as I followed the tutorial, I tried to follow the iot sensor tutorial but whenever I try to start the service it keeps stucking in this infinte loop -> Context Broker HTTP state : 000 (waiting for 200).

Any suggestions?

Details

- region:crete
- image: ubuntu 16.04

[image]
[putty infinite loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcEol.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the docker-compose did not include Orion (and MongoDB) instance which are required dependencies for this tutorial. We have updated the corresponding docker-compose file in order to include both dependencies and now it is working properly. Tips: do not forget to open the corresponding port (3000) in the security and assign a floating IP to the virtual machine to access to the /device/monitor (do not use localhost for accessing it).

Comment: thanks alot it works now , i have another question , in case i wanted to try IOT-Agent will i run to the same issue?

Comment: Do you mean the  202. Provisioning an IoT Agent? In that case the docker-compose file included the orion and mongodb images.